# Minimum number of steps to take to reach to a point

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

There are N buildings. Spiderman is having dinner in kth building. He got to know that there is a fire accident in Xth building. Problem is that at any time he can jump forward exactly F buildings or jump backwards exactly B buildings. He want to if it is possible to reach to the Xth building and if yes,he want to know the minimum number of jumps to reach to Xth building.

I tried to solve this using recursion. But i have some kind of intuition that it can be solved through some other logic. Can anybody suggest one?

Comment: Can you explain your recursive solution, it might be helpful for the answer-er to take it from there.

Comment: please consider making my answer as best answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is algorithmically simple once you get the math behind that.
You need to implement the Extended Euclidean Algorithm and few more things.

Let `M = X - K`, you want to check if `M = H F + K B` for some integers `H, K`.

The answer (is called Bezout's Identity) is that equation admits a solution if and only if `M` is divisible by the GCD (greatest common divisor) of `F` and `B`, we call it `D`.

Let suppose that a solution exists, then you can solve

`H F + K B = D`.

Call `(H,K) = (S_H, S_K)` any of its solution, for finding it use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Then there exist infinite solutions `(T_H, T_K)`, one for each integer `L`, and these are all of the form

```
T_H = S_H + L B/D

T_K = S_K - L F/D
```

You are interested in the solution with minimum values of `|T_H| + |T_K|`, this can again be computed theoretically, or with a simple for loop checking for the minimum, it is a piecewise linear functions which goes to infinite when `L` is approaching +- infinite.

For the background math look for the Bezout's identity, it is full of material online.

EDIT: this seems to contain all you need http://public.csusm.edu/aitken_html/m422/Handout1.pdf

Comment: Nice answer, quick question. If `M = X - N`, according to the OP's convention the fire is in the `Xth` building and there are `N` buildings. Wouldn't `X-N` be negative?

Comment: M represents a distance, so it has to be positive. If it is negative, simply replace `X-N` by `N-X`, compute the solutions using euclide's extended algorithm. Then `F` and `B` need to be swap to still obtain a good answer

Comment: I accidentally wrote `M = X - N` instead of `M = X - K`, now I edited the answer. There is no problem if M is negative: positive means that the accident is to the right (toward the building N), negative to the left (toward the first building). You can also change the sign as suggested if you like working with a positive number, it is just a matter of taste.